# how to i debug unable to import 'adoptions.models'?

Tags: python, json, django, eslint, pylint

The error says **Unable to import 'adoptions.models' and No value for argument 'dt' in unbound method call.**

**Program:**

```
from csv import DictReader
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from adoptions.models import Pet, Vaccine
from pytz import UTC


DATETIME_FORMAT = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'

VACCINES_NAMES = [
    'Canine Parvo',
    'Canine Distemper',
    'Canine Rabies',
    'Canine Leptospira',
    'Feline Herpes Virus 1',
    'Feline Rabies',
    'Feline Leukemia'
]

ALREADY_LOADED_ERROR_MESSAGE = """
If you need to reload the pet data from the CSV file,
first delete the db.sqlite3 file to destroy the database.
Then, run `python manage.py migrate` for a new empty
database with tables"""


class Command(BaseCommand):
    # Show this when the user types help
    help = "Loads data from pet_data.csv into our Pet model"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if Vaccine.objects.exists() or Pet.objects.exists():
            print('Pet data already loaded...exiting.')
            print(ALREADY_LOADED_ERROR_MESSAGE)
            return
        print("Creating vaccine data")
        for vaccine_name in VACCINES_NAMES:
            vac = Vaccine(name=vaccine_name)
            vac.save()
        print("Loading pet data for pets available for adoption")
        for row in DictReader(open('./pet_data.csv')):
            pet = Pet()
            pet.name = row['Pet']
            pet.submitter = row['Submitter']
            pet.species = row['Species']
            pet.breed = row['Breed']
            pet.description = row['Pet Description']
            pet.sex = row['Sex']
            pet.age = row['Age']
            raw_submission_date = row['submission date']
            submission_date = UTC.localize(
                datetime.strptime(raw_submission_date, DATETIME_FORMAT))
            pet.submission_date = submission_date
            pet.save()
            raw_vaccination_names = row['vaccinations']
            vaccination_names = [name for name in raw_vaccination_names.split('| ') if name]
            for vac_name in vaccination_names:
                vac = Vaccine.objects.get(name=vac_name)
                pet.vaccinations.add(vac)
            pet.save()
```

Comment: I assume adoption is your local module and you are doing an absolute import. The error seems to be about your project path in system path. You should share your project directory structure.

Comment: CONTRIBUTING.md
LICENSE
NOTICE
README.md
-wisdompets
    -adoptions
__    -init__.py
__    -pycache__
        -admin.py
        -apps.py
        -management
            -commands
__              -init__.py
__             -pycache__
                 -load_pet_data.py
        -migrations
        -models.py
        -tests.py
       -views.py
    -db.sqlite3
    -manage.py
    -pet_data.csv
    -wisdompets

Comment: thanks, but that quite difficult to understand without proper formatting please use https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree and instead of commenting update your question.